# CodeIgniter Views not parsing PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have CodeIgniter installed and running correctly, more or less. My application is loading the controller and displaying the view.

However, if using short tags `<?=base_url()?>` as I used to, this version does not parse them as PHP.

Should I include full tags `<?php echo base_url(); ?>` execution stops immediately at the first PHP tag.

PHP must be being parsed at some point, because when using short tags the controllers still load properly but produce HTML with short tags not parsed. What could be the issue?

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <img src="<?=base_url() . 'assets/images/cool_critter_logo_trans.png'?>" 
            alt="Cool Critters Logo" id="logo_image" />
        <h1>Welcome to Cool Critters!</h1>

        <p>
            This website is undergoing some serious updates! Please be patient as we work behind the scenes
            to improve the functionality and look of the website!
        </p>

        <p>
            Cool Critters is your source for dog training and agility supplies, courses, and information.
        </p>

        <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This worked on a previous iteration on another server, and I broke something in the move.

Available here: http://107.21.96.179:81/

Comment: Can you post the code that is rendering your view? I think that may be the issue.

Comment: Did you load the url helper?  `$this->load->helper('url');`.

Comment: @ToothlessRebel -- It definitely sounds like you're getting (though perhaps not immediately seeing) a PHP error of some kind, so you should have a look in your `/applications/logs/` directory (if you've enabled logging in your config) or your PHP error logs.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your server is not allowing short tags. You can change a setting in the config file to allow CI to rewrite short tags on the fly.

Take a look starting at line 372: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Rewrite PHP Short Tags
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
| can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
| in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
*/
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;
```

and the docs:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/alternative_php.html

Comment: Changing this did not fix it.

Comment: Could you check the php.ini file and let us know what the value is for `short_open_tag`?

Comment: Did you restart the web server?

Comment: Yes, I did restart the server.

Comment: Your page is actually not even making it to the point where you write `<div id="container">`. When I pull up the site, I [get this html returned](http://pastebin.com/xWCD8ggc) - which is telling me that something in your header view is killing it.  Do you have error_reporting on? If so, are you getting anything?

Answer (score 3):

Just Roel says, if you don't load the helper the **base_url()** function doesn't work.

Add the helper loader in the constructor of the controller

```
 $this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Probably not, but the actual PHP code is not being parsed. It's in the HTML output, so it's not that I am getting an error or wrong results for lacking helpers.

Comment: You have an error (maybe a syntax error) on your header...
The page can be loaded all because is stoppig here on your CSS LINK:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="

Comment: Write also your header view file. Maybe we can find some mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

Some servers don't support the so-called short tags, so it's recommended that you write them out completely. Besides that, you must load the URL helper in order to use `base_url()` in your view.

Simply add `$this->load->helper('url');` to the constructor or where ever you load models, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not an issue with Codeigniter.  I use short-tags all over my views with no problems.

Codeigniter doesn't 'parse' views in the same way that Django or Ruby does.  The code is executed as standard php.

Are you sure you haven't disabled short-tags in your PHP config?  I would bet that is the problem.  If not, you probably aren't using the right syntax.

Comment: I didn't think it was Codeignitor issues, really, just a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter can rewrite shorttags on the fly. Look for "Rewrite short tags" in application/config/config.php

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the settings in CodeIgniter, PHP needs to allow short tags.

In php.ini, set:

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Restart apache.